# Vue CLI шаблон webpack как использовать postcss?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, postcss

1. Создаю новый проект с помощью Vue CLI по шаблону webpack.
2. В корне есть файл .postcssrc.js с конфигом postcss
3. Я хочу использовать SASS устанавливаю пакет postcss-scss и меняю .postcssrc.js на такой вид

**.postcssrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
    parser: 'postcss-scss',
    plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {}
    }
}
```

4. Создаю файл style.css

```html
$size: 29px;
$color: #0ee;
.top {
   font-size: $size;
   color: $color;
}
```

5. Импортирую в main.js

   import styles from './style.scss';

В итоге файл в страницу вставляется в таком же виде без обработки. То есть SASS синтаксис не парсится.

В чем ошибка? Как на только что созданный проект по шаблону webpack подключить SASS через PostCss?

Answer (score 0):

Через postcss никогда не ставил, но в документации написано так:

Нужные пакеты:

`npm install -D sass-loader node-sass`

В вашей конфигурации webpack:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules omitted

      // this will apply to both plain `.scss` files
      // AND `<style lang="scss">` blocks in `.vue` files
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  // plugin omitted
}
```

[Документация](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass).

Можно еще легко создать проект через `vue create hello-world`, там будет предложенно какой препроцессор использовать и там проще с конфигами. Можно через браузер, а не консоль создать проект: `vue ui`

[Документация](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create)